# How to extract numbers from a multi line string in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I have been struggling with the task of getting all numbers out of a multiline `string` called `price` (`product` is ok).

Im using python to scrape a website for product name and price which results in below output and written like that to the file:

```
Master C141,"

6

                    999

                        .
                        -
                "
Master 220,"

6

                    499

                        .
                        -
                "
Master C170,"

12

                    499
                        .
                        -
                "
```

I have tried many different code examples from Stackoverflow and several other sites but none have worked. What I would like to accomplish is an output like below:

> Master C141, 6999
>
> Master 220, 6499
>
> Master C170, 12499

**Here is the code:**

```
content = driver.page_source

products=[] #List to store name of the product
prices=[] #List to store price of the product

soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
for a in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'c-product-listing__col'}):
    name=a.find('h2', attrs={'class':'c-product-card__heading'})
    price=a.find('div', attrs={'class':'c-price-tag__price'})

    print(re.findall("\d+", price.text))
    
    products.append(name.text)
    prices.append(price.text)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Product Name':products,'Price':prices}) 
df.to_csv('products.txt', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer assumes we are starting with the text in your question:

```py
output = re.sub(r'\b(Master \w+,).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(?=\bMaster|$)', r'\1 \2\3\n', text, flags=re.S).strip()
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
Master C141, 6999
Master 220, 6499
Master C170, 12499
```

Here we are just capturing the `Master` term along with the two digits following it, and then combining to generate the output you want.  Note that we use the dot all flag so we can match content across lines.

Comment: Hi Tim and thanks. I cant get your code to work though so I tried the regex part on pythex.org and dont get any match...

Also, could you exemplify using the values in the objects "name" and "price" instead of the static text "Master"? The productname changes and could be anything. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe replace `Master` with `\w+`?  Please [check the demo here](https://rextester.com/EXVW36062) to see my answer working.  You can go from there.

Comment: Thanks Tim for your input!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, problem solved. Thanks to those who helped me in the right direction. The code might not be optimal, but it works :)

```
.....
.....
content = driver.page_source

products=[] #List to store name of the product
prices=[] #List to store price of the product
ratings=[] #List to store rating of the product

soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
for a in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'c-product-listing__col'}):
    name=a.find('h2', attrs={'class':'c-product-card__heading'})
    price=a.find('div', attrs={'class':'c-price-tag__price'})
    strProduct = name.text
    strPrice = price.text
    
    strProduct = re.match('[^,]+', strProduct)[0]
    strPrice = re.sub('\D', '', strPrice)
    
    products.append(strProduct)
    prices.append(strPrice)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Product Name':products,'Price':prices}) 
df.to_csv('products.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

#### What happens?

You already have a solution build in, only problem is you are not appending it to your list.

#### How to fix?

Append the result of your regex to your list:

```
prices.append(re.findall("\d+", price.text))
```

Added to your example:

```
...
products=[] #List to store name of the product
prices=[] #List to store price of the product

soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
for a in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'c-product-listing__col'}):
    name=a.find('h2', attrs={'class':'c-product-card__heading'})
    price=a.find('div', attrs={'class':'c-price-tag__price'})

    products.append(name.text)
    prices.append(re.findall("\d+", price.text))
...
```

Comment: **Hello HedgeHog
I could not get this line to work:** prices.append(re.findall("\d+", price.text))
**I had to use this :**
`strPrice = price.text
: strPrice = re.sub('\D', '', strPrice)`
**Thank you for your input!**